# Flutter - How to get a link to a specific item in the Listview builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, get

I'm creating a product list page. And I have created the row of items in the Listview builder. It works as tabs. If I click a button on another page, it redirects to the specified item page. How to achieve this?

In Onpressed I put "**Get.to(Homepage(1));**" -> I got error

How to use conditions to redirect to a specific item page?

Code:

```
 ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: productController.section.value
                                    .docs![menuCollectionIndex!].items!.length,
                                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                                  return Row(
                                    children: [
                                      if (index == 0)
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              stackIndex = 0;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Container(
                                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  right: 15),
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                      10, 8, 10, 8),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: const Color(0xffF0F2F5),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                              ),
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    "Featured",
                                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                      textStyle:
                                                          const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.w700,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(width: 11),
                                                  Container(
                                                    height: 24,
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            selectedMenu = index;
                                            selectedSubMenu = 0;
                                          });
                                          onChangeFilter();
                                        },
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                right: 15),
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                10, 8, 10, 8),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: selectedMenu == index
                                                  ? AppColors.secondaryColor
                                                  : Color(0xffF0F2F5),
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                            ),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  productController
                                                      .section
                                                      .value
                                                      .docs![
                                                          menuCollectionIndex!]
                                                      .items![index]
                                                      .name
                                                      .toString(),
                                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 14,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w700,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(width: 11),
                                                Container(
                                                  width: 24,
                                                  height: 24,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    image:
                                                        CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                      productController
                                                          .section
                                                          .value
                                                          .docs![
                                                              menuCollectionIndex!]
                                                          .items![index]
                                                          .imageUrl
                                                          .toString(),
                                                    ),
                                                  )),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }),
                              ),
```

Comment: You cannot get link to specific item in a list but you can redirect user to that page and then scroll in listview programatically to the index that you want.

Comment: Use indexes from your list and then load data from that specific index.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin, Thanks for your response! Can you send an example?